# Flash lite 1.1 Actionscript and PHP

Tags: php, actionscript, flashlite

i need help on getting data from my database using php on actionscript?

any advice on how i can use loadVariables() or getURL()

i know PHP but im new with actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the process:

- Use loadVariables to call the PHP script:

  - `loadVariables("params.php", target_mc);`
- URL encode the output from the database:

  - `echo urlencode($resultset)`